# Is suppressing `asyncio.CancelledError` acceptable here?

Tags: python, task, python-asyncio, cancellation, graceful-shutdown

Example:

```py
    with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
        [await t for t in asyncio.all_tasks(loop=self.loop)
            if t is not asyncio.current_task()]
```

To avoid `Task was destroyed but it is pending!` warning, I have to await the tasks after cancelling, but awaiting them leads to the terminal being spammed with `CancelledError`. I know it's cancelled but I don't need to see that.

Does using `contextlib.suppress` here intervene negatively with the cancellation? The only other way that I can avoid seeing the cancelled error (or task destroyed warning without awaiting) is to start my initial tasks with `asyncio.wait` rather than `asyncio.gather`. For some reason, `wait` appears to suppress exceptions. I use `return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION` on `wait` and `return_exceptions=True` on `gather`. But it seems that regardless of how I set their keyword args, `gather` prints exceptions while `wait` does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CancelledError` is used for two purposes in asyncio: one is to signal a cancellation *request* - that's the one you get inside the coroutine being cancelled - and the other is to signal a cancellation *response* - that's the one you get in the coroutine that awaits the task. Suppressing the cancellation request is a bad idea because it makes the coroutine not respond to cancellation, causing issues later. But suppressing the response is perfectly fine because you might want to await the cancelled coroutine (e.g. to avoid this warning) without propagating an exception.

Note that the way you're doing doesn't quite look correct because the list comprehension will terminate on *first* `CancelledError`, so you won't get to awaiting the other coroutines. The correct way is to put `suppress` inside the loop, something like:

```
for t in tasks:
    with contextlib.suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
        await t

# or, simpler:
await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
```

`wait()` doesn't propagate exceptions because it returns sets of *futures* rather than their results. You'd get the exceptions if you tried to access the results of the returned futures. `gather(return_exceptions=True)` returns a mixture of results and exceptions and it should not raise anything. If it does, please edit the question to provide a minimal example.

Comment: That works, thanks. Not sure why I was getting exceptions from it earlier now, but it was probably the result of something else. I'll be using gather for it now though.

Comment: btw: `because the list comprehension will terminate on first CancelledError` are you sure about this? It seems like it completely ignores errors, differently from a normal `try/except`

Comment: @Break `suppress` will stop the exception from propagating, but the list comprehension will stop iterating as soon as it encounters an exception. E.g. try `with suppress(ZeroDivisionError): [(print(a), a/0) for a in range(10)]` and you'll see that only the first number is printed.

Comment: I strongly prefer the first variant (`suppress(CancelledError)`) as other possible exceptions are not silently ignored.